# Change base log formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Im trying to change the base log from ln to log with the following formula.

```
 y = a * ln⁡(x+c) + b
```

The ln equation is:

```
y = 17.686797186426052  * ln(x + 0.3) + -79.52230886298399
```

And considering that:

```
ln(X)=2.302585 log(X)
```

I was trying to change the equation to use log function (to this):

```
y = 17.686797186426052  * 2.302585 *  log(x + 0.3) + -79.52230886298399
```

However, for some reason it's not working. Id be really grateful for some pointers on where I might be going wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the formula as
$$
\begin{align}
y&=a\ln(x+c)+b\\
&=a\log_e(x+c)+b\\
&=a\frac{\log_k(x+c)}{\log_k e}+b\\
&=\frac{a}{\log_k e}\cdot\log_k(x+c)+b.\\
\end{align}
$$
If you want the logarithm in base-$10$, then you simply write
$$
y=\frac{a}{\log e}\cdot\log(x+c)+b.
$$
Now, you can plug in the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ without having trouble.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Im wondering what "log e" means? is that log(2.71828), or log(x) * 2.71828 ?

Comment: @Ke. $\log_e x$ means the base of logarithm is $e$, the Euler's number and $e=2.71828...$. To understand what is base in the logarithm, take a look this one:
$$
\log_a x=b\;\quad\;\Rightarrow\;\quad x=a^b.
$$
Similarly
$$
\log_e x=b\;\quad\;\Rightarrow\;\quad x=e^b.
$$
Hence, $\log_e x\neq\log(2.71828)$ or $\log_e x\neq2.71828\log(x)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Ke. You are welcome my friend. :)